# Validar url en visual basics

Tags: base-de-datos, validación

En la empresa tenemos un servidor que contiene archivos y documentos para clientes. Ellos acceden desde una url que les damos vía Internet. (dominio.es/carpeta/documento)

Estos datos están ligados a una base de datos de access, por lo que queremos añadir una función para verificar que existe esa url, para no tener que estar entrando al servidor donde se alojan los documentos y hacerlo directamente.

He probado este código, pero me decía únicamente que existía solo por el dominio, ya que probaba otra que no existía y esto lo validaba como que sí:

```
Private Function CheckConnection(sUrl As String) As Boolean  
    CheckConnection = InternetCheckConnection(sUrl, FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0&)  
End Function
```

Lo que quiero es que la función vaya a la url y solo me diga si la ruta existe o no.

Comment: No das suficiente información. Entorno de programación? ¿Web, Winforms? Existe ya una aplicación? Qué es lo que debe hacer la aplicación, pasar las URL, solo comprobar que el documento exista? Has intentado algo? Deberías mostrar el código

Comment: @RogerTorné disculpa, ahora añadiré esa información a la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por mi experiencia, la función `InternetCheckConnection` no es sencilla de manejar. Prefiero utilizar un `HttpWebRequest`. Previamente deberás hacer un `Imports System.Net`

```
Private Function CheckConnection(sUrl As String) As Boolean  
Try
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(sUrl), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Method = "HEAD"
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    response.Close()
    Return (response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK)
Catch
    Return False
End Try
```